# error: expected expression before { in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I am trying to initialize a one dimensional array as a member variable inside a class but I'm getting an expected expression error

here is the declaration inside the tetris.h file:

```
private:
    int* rotate(char piece,int rot);

    int width;
    int* heights;
    char* data[0];
    const string blockkeys;
    int *blocks;
};
```

and here is the constructor:

```
Tetris::Tetris(int w):blockkeys("IOJLZST"){
blocks = new int[7*4*2]={
    0,0,0,1,0,2,0,3,
    0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,
    0,0,1,0,1,1,1,2,
    0,0,1,0,0,1,0,2,
    0,0,1,0,0,1,-1,1,
    0,0,1,0,1,1,2,1,
    0,0,-1,1,1,1,2,1};
width=w;
heights=new int[width];
char *data[width];
for (unsigned int i=0; i<width; ++i){
    data[i]=new char[0];
    heights[i]=0;
}
}
```

the error is happening immediately after "new int[7*4*2]=" and before "{"

Comment: blocks is not a zero-length array.

Comment: @DanG., But `data` is.

Comment: `new int[7*4*2]` is not an lvalue. Why are you assigning to it?

Comment: But `data` is not causing any problems, in fact, data works perfectly

Comment: And what is the **actual** error being reported?

Comment: @DanG., Clang gives me *warning: zero size arrays are an extension* with `-pedantic`. GCC similarly gives *warning: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array 'data'*

Comment: `tetris.cpp:9:23: error: expected expression
        blocks = new int[56]={`
with an arrow pointing to the space between the = and {

Comment: @chris `blocks` is an after thought in order to allow rotation and adding of pieces. `data` already compiles and functions exactly as expected

Comment: Use `std::vector<int>` and in initialization list `blocks({ 0, 1})`

Comment: @NeilKirk I am not allowed to use std::vector in this assignment

Comment: Please clarify the array size expression `blocks[7*4*2]`.  Are you calculating space for 3 dimensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check the syntax? I'm afraid  "new int[7*4*2]=anything" is not a valid initializing expression in C++.

Also a zero-length array declaration is not valid.

**EDIT** After OP explanation:

Try declare the array static:

```
class Tetris {
    ....
    static int blocks[7*4*2];
};


int Tetris::blocks[7*4*2]={
    0,0,0,1,0,2,0,3,
    0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,
    0,0,1,0,1,1,1,2,
    0,0,1,0,0,1,0,2,
    0,0,1,0,0,1,-1,1,
    0,0,1,0,1,1,2,1,
    0,0,-1,1,1,1,2,1};
```

then use `blocks` in `Tetris` member functions.

Comment: Is there any way to instantiate this member variable without looping through and assigning each index to the number I want. I changed it to `new int[56]` and it still doesn't work

Comment: @DanG. The problem is the two `=` signs, not the multiplication

Comment: @Angew so how do i initialize this array in one line of code? I don't want to have to iterate through all 56 items

Comment: I'm afraid not. You need to loop through the whole allocated array and assign a value to each item separately (unless you have such array allocated and initialized before, in which case you might just `memmove` the contents—but that is calling for *serious* troubles...!).

Comment: But once you have such static initializer, what keeps you from allocating and using a static array? Do you *really need* allocate it in a heap with `new`?

Comment: I dont. I just have not been able to initialize it any way I have tried. This error seemed the most promising

Comment: Are you certain about the commas ',' inside the square brackets?  I don't think `blocks[7,4,2]` does what you think.  The OP used `blocks[7*4*2]`.